# Why does the id of python dict remains unchanged?

Tags: python

we have a dict like:

```
a = dict()
```

then we insert items, like:

```
for i in range(10**10):
    a[i] = 0
```

Why does the `id(a)` remains unchanged even when the dict is too large to reassign memory?

Comment: the object is same irrespective of the size right? So, `id` won't get changed

Comment: The dict object is still the same, regardless of the underlying memory.

Comment: This is actually I think a good question, I don't understand the downvotes. I think that it may have to do with the fact that `id` corresponds to the address of the object in memory only in CPython (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id))

Comment: I agree with @Djib2011 but it is actually not even a CPython thing. Whether it's the address in memory or not, *[it] is guaranteed to be unique and __constant__ for this object during its lifetime*

Comment: I agree, I don't understand the reason why this has been downvoted, this question is  good, in order to answer properly you'll need proper knowledge about the internal implementation... other answers will just be trivial, shallow or obvious... In this [routine](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1395-L1436), where is the memory allocation happening? +1 for a very good question coming from a new contributor :P

Comment: @BPL I don't think you were looking in the right place. [this function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c82dda1e08c4b74ca24f88d6a549d93108c319cf/Objects/dictobject.c#L1210) seems more relevant

Comment: It seems the whole magic is happening at [PyDict_SetItem](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c82dda1e08c4b74ca24f88d6a549d93108c319cf/Objects/dictobject.c#L1553-L1584) which it's where the internal memory will be resized

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by quoting what the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) state about id built-in function:

> id(object)
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer
> which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during
> its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the
> same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
> memory.

To understand your snippet:

```
a = dict()
for i in range(10**10):
    a[i] = 0
```

You need to understand first what's going on at line `a = dict()`, in this case you create a new python dictionary object and this is assigned to the variable `a`, at this point if we reference the docs part talking about `id` remaining unique through the whole lifetime of the object everything should make sense. For instance, let's say we've got this:

```
a = dict()
print(id(a))
a = dict() # New object
print(id(a))
```

Above you can clearly see how the id(a) should have changed and that's mainly because the object in the 2nd assignment to `a` is not the same. Another example:

```
a = dict() # id1
b = dict() # id2
a = b      # id2
```

Same thing, you've created 2 dict objects and in the 3rd assignment `a=b`, the `id(a)` will be `id2`, which will remain unique during the lifetime of the object referenced by vars `a` and `b`

Now, the interesting part of your question is you wondering why the `id` of `a` is not changing even if you're inserting new items to the dictionary. To understand that you'd need to be aware even if the underlying memory object will change eventually when `__setitem__` is called (underlying cpython implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c82dda1e08c4b74ca24f88d6a549d93108c319cf/Objects/dictobject.c#L1553-L1584)) and [resized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c82dda1e08c4b74ca24f88d6a549d93108c319cf/Objects/dictobject.c#L1052) at a particular growth rate the statement provided by the `id` docs will remain invariant through the object lifetime and the id will be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it is so inspring. This is my first question, so my description is so unclear , next time I will improve this.   And  in fact , what I wonder is , in python , **the function id() is the address of object in memory** , so why the dict object become too large, and reassign memory. But still with same id (mean same address?) , this is funny.

Comment: May be this answer is close to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753048/why-is-the-id-of-python-list-not-changing-after-append-operation-if-it-is-imple), but I am not sure.

Comment: That's perfectly fine :) ... at first when started asking in SO my questions were horrible, nowadays are slightly better yet I'll still find myself receiving a lot of downvotes ;) . Make sure you read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) link, that will help you out to improve future questions. About the current question, has your question been addressed by my answer? If it's so, consider mark it as valid